# fetching data from mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

i've been getting this issue this message that i can't seem to figure out the reason for it ,"mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli"
here's my code (i have an object called database aside repsonsable for the db connection and other db function);

```
 <?php 
      $sql="SELECT marque,cpu FROM pc";

      if ($result=mysqli_query($database->connection,$sql))
      {
          // Fetch one and one row
           while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
            { printf ("%s %s\n",$row[0],$row[1]);
            }
            // Free result set
            mysqli_free_result($result);
               }?>
```

and here is the part from the co.php responsable for the db connection

```
enter code here
       class MySQLDatabase {
       public $connection;
       public function open_conection(){
       $connection=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'alpha');
        if (!$connection){
         die ("can't connect:".mysqli_error());
    }else {

    $select_db=mysqli_select_db($connection,'alpha');
    if(!$select_db) {
        die ('no database:' .mysqli_error());

} 
}
}
}
```

Comment: Replace `$connection` with `$this->connection` in your `open_conection` function

Comment: thx for the reply charlotte but it gave an error saying that it didn't 'know' it i think $connection work fine there

Comment: You need to replace all `$connection` with `$this->connection` (also define this variable as member variable of your class) in your `open_conection` function. `$connection` isn't defined outside of the function `open_conection`. With making it a public member variable of your class, you can use it freely in your code, as long as the mysqli connection is open in `$database->connection`.

Comment: i actually defined it outside the function at the beginning of the class it goes like this : public $conection sorry i didn't mention it

Comment: You still need to use `$this->connection` since just `$connection` is a **local variable** in the method's scope.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35018883/i-need-help-properly-understanding-oop-in-php#comment57764729_35018883

Comment: when i do that i get errors about my co.php that the "$select_db=mysqli_select_db($this->connection,'alpha');" mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli 
mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Comment: Your error message is incomplete, *mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli...then what?*

Comment: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in 
mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your class like this:

```
class MySQLDatabase{

    private $connection;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'alpha');
        if (!$connection){die ("can't connect:".mysqli_error())};
    }

    public function  get_connection(){
        return $this->connection;
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
<?php 

include 'MySQLDatabase.php';

$db = new MySQLDatabase();
$conn = $db->get_connection();

$sql="SELECT marque,cpu FROM pc";
if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
    // Fetch one and one row
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    { 
        printf ("%s %s\n",$row[0],$row[1]);
    }
    // Free result set
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}else{
    echo 'query failed';
}
?>
```